# For Windows: Where to create connection profile for Fabric Composer / REST Server?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

The [information about creating a new connection profile](https://fabric-composer.github.io/installing/createconnectionprofile.html) references $HOME/.composer-connection-profiles as the directory to store connection profiles. Where is that located on Windows 7?

(Background: have both Fabric and Composer Playground running via docker-compose, using Docker Toolbox for Windows - now want to replace the playground by using the locally installed composer-cli, and locally installed composer-rest-server.)

Answer (score 0):

Composer doesn't currently support Windows 7. This problem is documented in a github issue [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/65)

Answer (score 0):

This may also be of interest -- connection profiles are also loaded from the COMPOSER_CONFIG environment variable:
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/602

Answer (score 0):

Mine are available on following location in Window 7 OS:

C:\Users\YourUserName\ .composer-connection-profiles

C:\Users\YourUserName\ .composer-credentials